# Importing Prebuilt Bootstrap Template into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to get a standard bootstrap + rails site by adding @import Bootstrap-sass into my css, and also importing the bootstrap gem. What I want to know is: I have found a bootstrap template on http://builtwithbootstrap.com/ that I like. Specifically, it is http://www.trippoinc.com/flexapp-demo How do I take this template and import it into a clean Rails + Bootstrap app? I can then delete the html, and re-add my own information on the page, as well as restyle it.

Thanks for all the help.